# RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (80) must match the size of tensor b (3) at non-singleton dimension 2

Tags: python, azure, tensorflow, yolo, azure-machine-learning-service

I am training Yolo-nas model with custom data.

when I am running the training code I am getting a Runtime Error of

```
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (80) must match the size of tensor b (3) at non-singleton dimension 2
```

Code: -

```
import torch
from super_gradients.training import models

DEVICE = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
MODEL_ARCH = 'yolo_nas_m'
#            'yolo_nas_m'
#            'yolo_nas_l'

model = models.get(MODEL_ARCH, pretrained_weights="coco").to(DEVICE)
```

**Data parameters**

```
MODEL_ARCH = 'yolo_nas_m'
BATCH_SIZE = 8
MAX_EPOCHS = 5
CHECKPOINT_DIR = 'new-checkpoints'
EXPERIMENT_NAME = "*********"
LOCATION = "********"
CLASSES = ["****","****","*****"]


dataset_params = {
    'data_dir': LOCATION,
    'train_images_dir':'new_train',
    'train_labels_dir':'new_train_labels',
    'val_images_dir':'new_valid',
    'val_labels_dir':'new_valid_labels',
    # 'test_images_dir':'test',
    # 'test_labels_dir':'108/test',
    'classes': CLASSES
}
```

**loading images and annotations**

```
from super_gradients.training.dataloaders.dataloaders import (
    coco_detection_yolo_format_train, coco_detection_yolo_format_val)

train_data = coco_detection_yolo_format_train(
    dataset_params={
        'data_dir': dataset_params['data_dir'],
        'images_dir': dataset_params['train_images_dir'],
        'labels_dir': dataset_params['train_labels_dir'],
        'classes': dataset_params['classes']
    },
    dataloader_params={
        'batch_size': BATCH_SIZE,
        'num_workers': 2
    }
)

val_data = coco_detection_yolo_format_val(
    dataset_params={
        'data_dir': dataset_params['data_dir'],
        'images_dir': dataset_params['val_images_dir'],
        'labels_dir': dataset_params['val_labels_dir'],
        'classes': dataset_params['classes']
    },
    dataloader_params={
        'batch_size': BATCH_SIZE,
        'num_workers': 2
    }
)
```

**Training Parameters**

```
from super_gradients.training.losses import PPYoloELoss
from super_gradients.training.metrics import DetectionMetrics_050
from super_gradients.training.models.detection_models.pp_yolo_e import PPYoloEPostPredictionCallback

train_params = {
    # ENABLING SILENT MODE
    'silent_mode': True,
    "average_best_models":True,
    "warmup_mode": "linear_epoch_step",
    "warmup_initial_lr": 1e-6,
    "lr_warmup_epochs": 3,
    "initial_lr": 5e-4,
    "lr_mode": "cosine",
    "cosine_final_lr_ratio": 0.1,
    "optimizer": "Adam",
    "optimizer_params": {"weight_decay": 0.0001},
    "zero_weight_decay_on_bias_and_bn": True,
    "ema": True,
    "ema_params": {"decay": 0.9, "decay_type": "threshold"},
    # ONLY TRAINING FOR 10 EPOCHS FOR THIS EXAMPLE NOTEBOOK
    "max_epochs": 25,
    "mixed_precision": False,
    "loss": PPYoloELoss(
        use_static_assigner=False,
        # NOTE: num_classes needs to be defined here
        num_classes=len(dataset_params['classes']),
        reg_max=16
    ),
    "valid_metrics_list": [
        DetectionMetrics_050(
            score_thres=0.1,
            top_k_predictions=300,
            # NOTE: num_classes needs to be defined here
            num_cls=len(dataset_params['classes']),
            normalize_targets=True,
            post_prediction_callback=PPYoloEPostPredictionCallback(
                score_threshold=0.01,
                nms_top_k=1000,
                max_predictions=300,
                nms_threshold=0.7
            )
        )
    ],
    "metric_to_watch": 'mAP@0.50'
}
```

**Defining model**

```
from super_gradients.training import Trainer

CHECKPOINT_DIR = CHECKPOINT_DIR
trainer = Trainer(experiment_name=EXPERIMENT_NAME, ckpt_root_dir=CHECKPOINT_DIR)
```

**Training**

```
trainer.train(model=model,
              training_params=train_params,
              train_loader=train_data,
              valid_loader=val_data)
```

Error logs: -

```
The console stream is now moved to new-checkpoints/faucet_poc/console_Jul19_20_50_30.txt
[2023-07-19 20:50:33] INFO - sg_trainer.py - Using EMA with params {'decay': 0.9, 'decay_type': 'threshold'}
/anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py:546: UserWarning: Can't initialize NVML
  warnings.warn("Can't initialize NVML")
[2023-07-19 20:50:39] INFO - sg_trainer_utils.py - TRAINING PARAMETERS:
    - Mode:                         Single GPU
    - Number of GPUs:               0          (0 available on the machine)
    - Dataset size:                 120        (len(train_set))
    - Batch size per GPU:           8          (batch_size)
    - Batch Accumulate:             1          (batch_accumulate)
    - Total batch size:             8          (num_gpus * batch_size)
    - Effective Batch size:         8          (num_gpus * batch_size * batch_accumulate)
    - Iterations per epoch:         15         (len(train_loader))
    - Gradient updates per epoch:   15         (len(train_loader) / batch_accumulate)

[2023-07-19 20:50:46] INFO - base_sg_logger.py - [CLEANUP] - Successfully stopped system monitoring process
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 1
----> 1 trainer.train(model=model,
      2               training_params=train_params,
      3               train_loader=train_data,
      4               valid_loader=val_data)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/super_gradients/training/sg_trainer/sg_trainer.py:1361, in Trainer.train(self, model, training_params, train_loader, valid_loader, test_loaders, additional_configs_to_log)
   1354 if (
   1355     device_config.multi_gpu == MultiGPUMode.DISTRIBUTED_DATA_PARALLEL
   1356     and hasattr(self.train_loader, "sampler")
   1357     and hasattr(self.train_loader.sampler, "set_epoch")
   1358 ):
   1359     self.train_loader.sampler.set_epoch(epoch)
-> 1361 train_metrics_tuple = self._train_epoch(context=context, silent_mode=silent_mode)
   1363 # Phase.TRAIN_EPOCH_END
   1364 # RUN PHASE CALLBACKS
   1365 train_metrics_dict = get_metrics_dict(train_metrics_tuple, self.train_metrics, self.loss_logging_items_names)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/super_gradients/training/sg_trainer/sg_trainer.py:442, in Trainer._train_epoch(self, context, silent_mode)
    439     outputs = self.net(inputs)
    441     # COMPUTE THE LOSS FOR BACK PROP + EXTRA METRICS COMPUTED DURING THE LOSS FORWARD PASS
--> 442     loss, loss_log_items = self._get_losses(outputs, targets)
    444 context.update_context(preds=outputs, loss_log_items=loss_log_items)
    445 self.phase_callback_handler.on_train_batch_loss_end(context)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/super_gradients/training/sg_trainer/sg_trainer.py:475, in Trainer._get_losses(self, outputs, targets)
    473 def _get_losses(self, outputs: torch.Tensor, targets: torch.Tensor) -> Tuple[torch.Tensor, tuple]:
    474     # GET THE OUTPUT OF THE LOSS FUNCTION
--> 475     loss = self.criterion(outputs, targets)
    476     if isinstance(loss, tuple):
    477         loss, loss_logging_items = loss

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/super_gradients/training/losses/ppyolo_loss.py:790, in PPYoloELoss.forward(self, outputs, targets)
    788 if self.use_varifocal_loss:
    789     one_hot_label = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(assigned_labels, self.num_classes + 1)[..., :-1]
--> 790     loss_cls = self._varifocal_loss(pred_scores, assigned_scores, one_hot_label)
    791 else:
    792     loss_cls = self._focal_loss(pred_scores, assigned_scores, alpha_l)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py310_sdkv2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/super_gradients/training/losses/ppyolo_loss.py:894, in PPYoloELoss._varifocal_loss(pred_logits, gt_score, label, alpha, gamma)
    891 @staticmethod
    892 def _varifocal_loss(pred_logits: Tensor, gt_score: Tensor, label: Tensor, alpha=0.75, gamma=2.0) -> Tensor:
    893     pred_score = pred_logits.sigmoid()
--> 894     weight = alpha * pred_score.pow(gamma) * (1 - label) + gt_score * label
    895     loss = -weight * (gt_score * torch.nn.functional.logsigmoid(pred_logits) + (1 - gt_score) * torch.nn.functional.logsigmoid(-pred_logits))
    896     return loss.sum()

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (80) must match the size of tensor b (3) at non-singleton dimension 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the solution.

I am doing a very silly mistake here.

```
import torch
from super_gradients.training import models

DEVICE = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
MODEL_ARCH = 'yolo_nas_m'
#            'yolo_nas_m'
#            'yolo_nas_l'

model = models.get(MODEL_ARCH, pretrained_weights="coco").to(DEVICE)
```

In the above code snippet, I am not defining the number of classes.

So the model is taking coco predefined classes of 80, thats why the error is showing up

```
import torch
from super_gradients.training import models

DEVICE = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
MODEL_ARCH = 'yolo_nas_m'
#            'yolo_nas_m'
#            'yolo_nas_l'

model = models.get(MODEL_ARCH, pretrained_weights="coco",num_classes=len(CLASSES)).to(DEVICE)
```

I got the solution from here https://github.com/Deci-AI/super-gradients/issues/1302#issuecomment-1643249856